# Dynamically changing the connection string for a gridview with a button?

Tags: asp.net

I have a log file in several SQL databases.

I want to have a grid on an ASP page that is bound to one of them.

I want to have several buttons on the page that will change what table fills the gridview.

This is an ASP VB web site project.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the "other" connection strings defined in your web.config?

Comment: Well if you do, then you just have the click handler for your button(s) read the necessary connection string, pass it to the logic (data-access layer class/method) that gets the data to fill the grid. Or you could hard-code the connection string in the button event handler code, but that is less flexible; it depends if you want the connection string to be changed without recompiling your code or not.

Comment: Strings added to web config. What you type makes sense, I am having problem with execution....

Comment: Is this ASP.NET or ASP-Classic - there are two very different answers depending on which it is... You'll want to edit the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

just have the buttons bind the data through different methods. for example, button A calls method A which uses connection string A to fill the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. Hope this code help some one else. Thanks to all who commented...

Web.config Info:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Data1" connectionString="Data Source=Server1;Initial Catalog=DatabaseSame;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="Data2" connectionString="Data Source=Server2;Initial Catalog=DatabaseSame;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="Data3" connectionString="Data Source=Server3;Initial Catalog=DatabaseSame;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Webform has a data grid and multiple buttons to choose which database and or server

Code behind:

```
Imports System.Configuration

Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub SetNewConnectionForDataSource(ByVal strConnectionName As String)
    'Pull data from webconfig based on the connection name
    Dim strConnectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(strConnectionName).ConnectionString

    Me.SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = strConnectionString

    'Save to viewstate for postback
    ViewState("CurrentConnection") = strConnectionString

    'Let user know what connection they are viewing
    lblEnvironment.Text = strConnectionName

End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If IsPostBack Then
        Me.SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = ViewState("CurrentConnection")
    Else
        'First page load, set database
        SetNewConnectionForDataSource("Data1")
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub btnOne_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDev.Click
    SetNewConnectionForDataSource("Data1")
End Sub

Protected Sub btnTwo_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnProd.Click
    SetNewConnectionForDataSource("Data2")
End Sub

Protected Sub btnThree_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnProd.Click
    SetNewConnectionForDataSource("Data3")
End Sub


End Class
```